# The output is different by the two command: conda env list; conda info --envs

Tags: conda

Thank you for your attention. 
I just 'usermod' the Joel from /home to /data. I think if I modified the .condarc and .bash_profile files, the anaconda would work in the new path /data/joel/usr/local/
However, I found that the output is different when using the followed commands.

Joel@machine:~$ conda env list

```
# conda environments:
#
h2o_python35             /home/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/h2o_python35
py27                     /home/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/py27
py35                     /home/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/py35
py36cu80torch            /home/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/py36cu80torch
py3cu80torch             /home/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/py3cu80torch
root                  *  /home/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3
```

Joel@machine:~$ conda info --envs

```
# conda environments:
#
h2o_python35             /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/h2o_python35
py27                     /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/py27
py3                      /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/py3
py35                     /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/py35
py36cu80torch            /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/py36cu80torch
py3cu80torch             /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/py3cu80torch
test                     /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/test
root                  *  /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3
```

Thank you all.

attached information:
Joel@machine:~$ conda info

Current conda install:

```
           platform : linux-64
      conda version : 4.3.30
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.30
conda-build version : 3.0.19
     python version : 3.6.2.final.0
   requests version : 2.14.2
   root environment : /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3  (writable)
default environment : /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3
   envs directories : /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/envs
                      /data/Joel/.conda/envs
      package cache : /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/pkgs
                      /data/Joel/.conda/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/linux-64
                      https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
        config file : /data/Joel/.condarc
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.30 requests/2.14.2 CPython/3.6.2 Linux/3.16.0-33-generic debian/jessie/sid glibc/2.19
```

Comment: Thank you merv. I added the output of conda info. Please review it again.

Comment: That's quite an old Conda version. It might take some archeology to troubleshoot why the `conda-env` and `conda` commands yield different results. Do you get a difference in paths with `which conda` and `which conda-env`?

Comment: Thanks.  which conda --> /data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/conda

Comment: which conda-env -->/data/Joel/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/conda-env